# Convert a point and Euler angles to 3 points in 3D space

Tags: 3d, euler-angles

I have a 3D point and 3 Euler angles representing a camera pose, like  (X Y Z A B C),  where (X, Y, Z) is the 3D position of the camera and (A, B, C) are the Euler angles (in degrees) that represent the camera orientation.

I would like to get 3 points. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

what you need is some math. you can calculate your goal with rotation matrix. its not that hard.
i'll give you a wiki link as hint.

good luck

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Rotation_matrix_.E2.86.94_Euler_axis.2Fangle

Comment: Is the transformation matrix containing the 3 points I am looking for? How do I merge the first 3D point I already have with the matrix?